# How to Communicate/send data from parent Fragment to a child Fragment inside ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a parent Fragment that contains a `ViewPager`.

I want to communicate to one of the children of that `ViewPager`, but I don't know how to retrieve a child of that `ViewPager`.  There's no obvious method to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the below `updateFragments()` method when you have performed the search operation. If you want to apply filter to both the fragments then you just have to remove the `if-else` block and execute both the operations which are currently inside the `if-else` block.

- **Kotlin Solution**

**HomeFragment.kt**

```kotlin
private fun updateFragments(filterText:String) {
    if (viewpager?.currentItem == 0)
        ((viewpager?.adapter?.instantiateItem(viewpager, 0)) as FragmentA).updateFragment(filterText)
    else
        ((viewpager?.adapter?.instantiateItem(viewpager, 1)) as FragmentB).updateFragment(filterText)
}
```

**FragmentA.kt & FragmentB.kt**

```kotlin
fun updateFragment(filterText: String) {
    // Perform what you want to do with the 'filterText'
}
```

- **Java Solution**

**HomeFragment.java**

```java
private void updateFragments(String filterText) {
    if (viewpager == null) return // some error occurred
    if (viewpager.getCurrentItem() == 0)
        ((FragmentA)(viewpager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewpager, 0))).updateFragment(filterText)
    else
        ((FragmentB)(viewpager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewpager, 1))).updateFragment(filterText)
}
```

**FragmentA.java & FragmentB.java**

```java
public void updateFragment(String filterText) {
    // Perform what you want to do with the 'filterText'
}
```

Comment: Thank you harsh. Am using java, but I will try to understand it , and apply it in java, thank you

Comment: @qasim, I have added java solution. Hope it helps you. :-)

Comment: Its working very fine. This help me , thank you @harsh. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @qasim, Glad that it helped you. :-)